# Count total rows of gridview with pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with paging. When I try to count gridview row with gridview.rows.count, It gives me row count for current page only.

How can I get total rows of GridView irrespective of page index?

// Here is the code of .aspx page

```
<%@ Page Title="Search candidates based on vacancy" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/HR     Department/hrmasterpage.master"
   AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="searcAppForVac.aspx.cs"     Inherits="HR_Department_searcAppForVac" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"       runat="Server">    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="tdtitle">
            Search Candidates
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="RowHeight" width="20%">
                                Select Company
                            </td>
                            <td width="30%">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="companyList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True"
                                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="companyList_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="150px">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="-Select Company-" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td width="20%">
                                Select Department
                            </td>
                            <td width="30%">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="deptList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True"
                                    onclick="Validate();" OnSelectedIndexChanged="deptList_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                    Width="150px">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">-Select Department-</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="RowHeight" width="20%">
                                Select Vacancy
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="3" width="*">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="vacanyList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                                    Width="200px" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                    onselectedindexchanged="vacanyList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">-Select Vacancy-</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4" align="center">
                                &nbsp;
                                <asp:Label ID="notifyLbl" runat="server" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Red" 
                                    Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <asp:Label ID="titleLbl" runat="server" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Red" 
                                    Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <asp:GridView ID="appForVacGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" AllowPaging="True" 
                                    onpageindexchanging="appForVacGrid_PageIndexChanging" GridLines="None" 
                                    PageSize="3">
                                    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                App.ID
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="appIdLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AppId") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                First Name
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="firstNameLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AppFirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                Last Name
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lastNameLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AppLastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                Qualification
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="qualiNameLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QualiName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                &nbsp;Experience
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalExpYear") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                EmailId
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="emailLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AppEmailId1") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                Send Mail
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="sendMailBox" runat="server" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
                                        HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                        VerticalAlign="Top" />
                                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
                                        Font-Size="Medium" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4" align="center">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="4">
                                <asp:Button ID="sendMailBtn" runat="server" Height="40px" Text="SEND MAIL" 
                                    Width="100px" onclick="sendMailBtn_Click" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <%--<td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>--%>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="companyList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="deptList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="appForVacGrid" EventName="pageindexchanged" />
                </Triggers>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function alertOnBadSelection() {
        var select = document.getElementById('companyList');
        if (select.options[select.selectedIndex].value == "-Select Company-") {
            alert('Please Select Company!');
            return false;
        }
    }    
</script>
```

// This is code of my aspx.cs page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;

public partial class HR_Department_searcAppForVac : System.Web.UI.Page
{
DataOperation oDo = new DataOperation();
AppVacancyDetailClass objAppVacDetail = new AppVacancyDetailClass();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyLbl.Visible = false;
    titleLbl.Visible = false;
    sendMailBtn.Visible = false;
    try
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Disable department dropdown list and vacancy dropdown list till company is not selected.
            deptList.Enabled = false;
            vacanyList.Enabled = false;
            //Fill Company dropdown list.
            DataTable objCmpnyTable = oDo.DropDownList("select * from tblCompanyMaster");
            if (objCmpnyTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                companyList.DataSource = objCmpnyTable;
                companyList.DataValueField = "CompId";
                companyList.DataTextField = "CompName";
                companyList.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                notifyLbl.Visible = true;
                notifyLbl.Text = "There is not any company in the list.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (companyList.SelectedIndex <= 0)
            {
                //Disable department dropdown list and vacancy dropdown list till company is not selected.
                deptList.Enabled = false;
                vacanyList.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
          throw;
     }
 }
protected void companyList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Disable vacancy dropdown list till depratment list is not selected
    vacanyList.Enabled = false;
    appForVacGrid.DataSource = null;
    appForVacGrid.DataBind();
    try
    {
        if (companyList.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            deptList.Enabled = true;
            deptList.Items.Clear();
            string str = "select * from vwCompWiseList where CompId=" + companyList.SelectedValue;
            DataTable objDeptTable = oDo.DropDownList("select DeptId,DeptName from vwCompWiseDept where CompId= "+companyList.SelectedValue);
            if (objDeptTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                deptList.DataSource = objDeptTable;
                deptList.DataTextField = "DeptName";
                deptList.DataValueField = "deptId";
                deptList.DataBind();
                deptList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Department--", "-1"));
            }
            else 
            {
                deptList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--No Departments--", "-1"));
                notifyLbl.Visible = true;
                notifyLbl.Text = "No Departments Available in " + companyList.SelectedItem.Text;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            notifyLbl.Visible = true;
            notifyLbl.Text = "Select Company....";
            appForVacGrid.DataSource = null;
            appForVacGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }    
}
protected void deptList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (deptList.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            vacanyList.Enabled = true;
            vacanyList.Items.Clear();
            DataTable objVacancytbl = oDo.DropDownList("select VacId,VacTitle from tblVacancyMaster where DeptId =" + deptList.SelectedValue + " and CompId=" + companyList.SelectedValue);
            if (objVacancytbl.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                vacanyList.DataSource = objVacancytbl;
                vacanyList.DataValueField = "VacId";
                vacanyList.DataTextField = "VacTitle";
                vacanyList.DataBind();
                vacanyList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Vacancy--", "-1"));
                appForVacGrid.DataSource = null;
                appForVacGrid.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                notifyLbl.Visible = true;
                notifyLbl.Text = "ALL VACANCIES ARE CLOSED IN "+" "+deptList.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper();
                vacanyList.Enabled = false;
                appForVacGrid.DataSource = null;
                appForVacGrid.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            notifyLbl.Visible = true;
            notifyLbl.Text = "Select Department...";
            appForVacGrid.DataSource = null;
            appForVacGrid.DataBind();
            vacanyList.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {            
        throw;
    }
}
protected void vacanyList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable AppListTbl = objAppVacDetail.GetValue("CompId=" + companyList.SelectedValue + " and DeptId=" + deptList.SelectedValue + " and VacId=" + vacanyList.SelectedValue);
        if (AppListTbl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            appForVacGrid.DataSource = AppListTbl;
            appForVacGrid.DataBind();
            appForVacGrid.Columns[5].Visible = false;
            Session.Add("snAppListTbl", AppListTbl);
            titleLbl.Visible = true;
            titleLbl.Text = AppListTbl.Rows.Count.ToString() + " " + "CANDIDATE(S) ARE ELIGIBLE FOR THE POST OF" + " " + vacanyList.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper() + ".";
            sendMailBtn.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            notifyLbl.Visible = true;
            notifyLbl.Text = "ALL VACANCIES ARE CLOSED IN " + " " + deptList.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper();
            appForVacGrid.DataSource = null;
            appForVacGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
protected void appForVacGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    //DataTable AppListTbl = (DataTable)Session["snAppListTbl"];
    titleLbl.Visible = true;
    titleLbl.Text = ((DataTable)Session["snAppListTbl"]).Rows.Count.ToString() + " " + "CANDIDATE(S) ARE ELIGIBLE FOR THE POST OF" + " " + vacanyList.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper() + ".";
    appForVacGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    appForVacGrid.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["snAppListTbl"];
    appForVacGrid.DataBind();
    sendMailBtn.Visible = true;
}
protected void sendMailBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable AppListTable = ((DataTable)Session["snAppListTbl"]);
    int intTotalRows = AppListTable.Rows.Count;
    string strFromId="",strToId="",strCcId="",strBccId="";
    string strVacTitle="",strCompName="",strMailBody="";
    string strSubject = "Rgarding Selection of Your Resume";
    Label EmailLbl;
    //for (int intRow = 0; intRow < intTotalRows; intRow++)
    foreach (GridViewRow Row in appForVacGrid.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox objSendMail = (CheckBox)Row.FindControl("sendMailBox");
        //CheckBox objSendMail = (CheckBox)appForVacGrid.Rows[Row].FindControl("sendMailBox");
        if (objSendMail.Checked)
        {
            if (strToId == "")
            {
                //strToId = AppListTable.Rows[Row]["AppEmailId1"].ToString();
                EmailLbl = (Label)Row.FindControl("emailLbl");
                strToId = EmailLbl.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                //strToId += "," + AppListTable.Rows[Row]["AppEmailId1"].ToString();
                EmailLbl = (Label)Row.FindControl("emailLbl");
                strToId +=","+ EmailLbl.Text;
            }
        }
    }
    strVacTitle = AppListTable.Rows[intTotalRows]["VacTitle"].ToString();
    strCompName = AppListTable.Rows[intTotalRows]["CompName"].ToString();
    strMailBody = CommonProcedures.GetMailBody(strVacTitle, strCompName);
    //CommonProcedures.SendMail(strFromId, strToId, strCcId, strBccId, strSubject, null, strMailBody, false);
}
}
```

Now I want to send mail to all those candidates whose checkbox is checked..
I trid so many things but didnt get any solution

Comment: try this
appForVacGrid.AllowPaging = false;
appForVacGrid.DataBind();
// write code for sending mails
appForVacGrid.AllowPaging = true;
appForVacGrid.DataBind();

Comment: @Mukesh.. What is the benefit of doing like this??? I tried this but it doesn't make any difference. I want to select checkboxes from different pages and mail should be sent in just one click to all those rows whose checkbox is selected....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, that's true, it will only return the current page rows only. If you really want to get the total row count, you need to get from your datasource instead.

Like... if you have DataTable then it will be like...

```
DataTable.Rows.Count
```

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar. I got total row Count with datatable.rows.count. Now if I want to manipulate all rows of first page then how can I do so???

Comment: You need to iterate all rows.  foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar. I want to iterate gridview rows and for each row I want to fetch value from datatable for that perticluar row which is not possible with foreach()

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtaar..foreach() also gives rows of current page only. It is not giving all row of gridview

Comment: then you can iterate your datasource;

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar.. I tried to iterate my datatable but it throws error when datatable.row.count exceeds pagesize of gridview...

Answer (score 21):

if you're using sqldatasource or objectdatasource You need to use the ReturnValue of the ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs or SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs while handling the datasource's Selected event.

If you are using sqldatasource, you can count the total rows using the 'Selected' event which gets fired after the select operation has been completed.

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
  int rowCount = e.AffectedRows;
}
```

If you're using object data source, it's important to note that the Selected event on the ODS gets called twice, once returning the data set, and again to call the method you specified in the SelectCountMethod property.  Simply test to see if the return is an Int32 in the event.

```
protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selected(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ReturnValue.GetType() == typeof(System.Int32))
        int rowCount = (Int32)e.ReturnValue;
}
```

You can find a working example at: http://www.webswapp.com/codesamples/aspnet20/dropdownlist_gridview/default.aspx

if your GridView is being filled by a DataSet or DataTable:

```
int rowCount=((DataTable)Customer).Rows.Count;
```

If you are binding the list or array of objects then you can do the following:

```
int rowCount = ((Customer[])gv.DataSource).Count;
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes I think using PagedDataSource is a better option. I'm using it.

```
PagedDataSource pds = new PagedDataSource();
pds.DataSource = dt_main.DefaultView;
pds.AllowPaging = true;
pds.PageSize = 8;

int currentPage;

if (Request.QueryString["page"] != null)
{
    currentPage = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["page"]);
}
else
{
    currentPage = 1;
}

pds.CurrentPageIndex = currentPage - 1;
Label1.Text = "Page " + currentPage + " of " + pds.PageCount;

if (!pds.IsFirstPage)
{
    linkPrev.NavigateUrl = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath + "?page=" + (currentPage - 1);
}

if (!pds.IsLastPage)
{
    linkNext.NavigateUrl = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath + "?page=" + (currentPage + 1);
}
gridMain.DataSource = pds;
gridMain.DataBind();
```

Comment: @Mukesh.... My problem is I have checkboxes in template field of grieview. I want to retrive all checked box from gridview and based on that checked box I want ot fetch record from datatable. Its not possible with your way... Is there any other way out???

Comment: "I want to retrive all checked box from gridview and based on that checked box I want ot fetch record from datatable"
The line is little confusing.

Can you post your code, then I can help you easily.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
int _TotalRecs = ((System.Data.DataView)GridView.DataSource).Count;
int _CurrentRecStart = GridView.PageIndex * GridView.PageSize + 1;
int _CurrentRecEnd = GridView.PageIndex * GridView.PageSize + GridView.Rows.Count;

lblTitle.Text = string.Format("Displaying {0} to {1} of {2} records found", _CurrentRecStart, _CurrentRecEnd, _TotalRecs);
```

For e.g. Output will be like below....

> **Displaying 1 to 15 of 67 records found.**

Comment: Short and effective.. great solution.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a paged datasource to bind the gridview and it will be very easy for custom paging and get the page count.

Comment: parogrammer.. But I dont have any paged datasource. I have datatable which contains all rows of gridview. Out of that only part of rows are visible in gridview as per page size. When I loop through girdview with datatable.rows.count,It throws error after current page. Is there any way to get current page count irrespective of datasource or datatable. If it can be achived with datatable then how to get row count of current page using datatable??

Comment: @Chirag Fanse: It throws an esxception because you do not have the data on postbacks. Store the `DataTable.Rows.Count()` in a session variable to persist it on postbacks.

Comment: if you have already bound to a datatable then you can use DataTable.Rows.Count to get the row count. If you are interested in using paged datasource it is for custom binding, thats why I told. Please see the link. http://forums.asp.net/t/1451791.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
            if (Grid.DataSource == null)
                return 0;
            else if (Grid.DataSource.GetType() == typeof(DataTable))
                return (Grid.DataSource as DataTable).Rows.Count;
            else if (Grid.DataSource.GetType().IsGenericType)
                return (Grid.DataSource as IList).Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `gridview` which will be filled using a `datatable` or `dataset` then count the `datatable` or `dataset` (`ds.table(0).rows.count`) 
For example

```
For cnt1 = 0 To Total_batchRecords - 1
   dgchgsdtl1.Rows.Item(cnt1).FindControl("ControlName"), Label)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
(gridview1.DataSource as DataTable).Rows.Count();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.

Answer (score 0):

try (gridView.DataSource as IEnumerable<object>).Count() for main collection

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding using the datatable or other datasource you can show the total records from the datasource.
For example

```
  if (dtLog != null && dtLog .Rows.Count >= 0)
            {
                lblTotal.Text = "Total " + Convert.ToString(dtLog .Rows.Count) + " records.";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<font-color='red'><b>dim dt as datatable<Br>
dt=gridview1.datasource<br>
msgbox (dt.rows.count)<b></font>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider adding an explanation to your answer in addition to just the code.

Comment: Please double-check to be sure the code is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
               int a = grdvw.PageIndex;
               int rowcount=0;

                for (int i = 0; i < grdvw.PageCount; i++)
                {
                    grdvw.SetPageIndex(i);
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdvw.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                        {
                          rowcount++;
                        }
                    }
               }

             grdvw.SetPageIndex(a);
```