# Get Total No of Records in Gridview Pager

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

How to get the **total number of records** in the *footer of gridview.* i have the source but it is not showing me correct no of records. It shows everything else correct. Just the **total records** is **not showing correct**.

```
<PagerTemplate>
    Showing
    <%= grdProductStock.PageIndex * grdProductStock.PageSize + 1%>
      to
   <%= grdProductStock.PageIndex * grdProductStock.PageSize + grdProductStock.Rows.Count%>
      of
   <%= grdProductStock.PageCount * grdProductStock.Rows.Count%>
      Records
 </PagerTemplate>
```

Comment: buttompager is displaying or not?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788329/count-total-rows-of-gridview-with-pagination

Comment: yes it is displaying but it is not showing correct values of total record. rest it is showing correct.

Comment: @yogi:no it is not dublicate. i want to go according to this code. i guess there is some problem in calculation of this indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I found it some where while googling a long time ago.

```
protected void grdProductStock_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (grdProductStock!= null)
    {
        //Showing Search Result Count
        //Get Top Pager Row from a gridview
        GridViewRow row = grdProductStock.TopPagerRow;
        if (row != null)
        {
            //Create one Cell for adding in my current paging strip
            TableCell infocell = new TableCell();
            infocell.Text = ” Page ” + (grdProductStock.PageIndex + 1).ToString() + ” of ” +grdProductStock.PageCount.ToString() +“(” + table.Rows.Count.ToString() + ” Records)”;

            //Getting table which shows PagingStrip
            Table tbl = (Table)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];

            //Will Find  table
            tbl.Rows[0].Cells.Add(infocell);
        }
    }
}
```

Here table is your datasource i.e., dataset.tables[0].rows.count. datatable.rows.count etc.

Comment: what is this _totalrowscount ? which variable ?

Comment: @moiz kachwala: Just changed that total no of rows in dataset/datatable rows

Comment: have u tested this code ? as its not working. and you have code with gridview ?