# asp.net pager custom text before pager

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, paging

I'm using a GridView with a pager in asp.net, I want to display the count of pages in this way:

5 Pages:  1  2  3  4  5

Is there any solution for it without creating a completely new PagerTemplate?

Comment: Something like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209666/get-total-no-of-records-in-gridview-pager)?

Comment: Yes exactly, but the main problem is to show the page, because the pagertemplate overrides the page completely

Comment: check this
http://www.devcurry.com/2011/01/display-page-count-in-aspnet-gridview.html

Comment: I've allready seen this, but it have to be displayed in the same line as the pages.