# Total Row Count SqlDataSource GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource, rowcount

So I have a GridView set up to a SqlDataSource. Paging is enabled and I have a drop down menu that changes the number of rows displayed per page. I am able get the total of rows displayed in a single page but I want to show the total number of rows as well. (Like this: "Showing 1 - 25 of 315").

So, my questions are:

1) How do I get the total number of rows for the entire DataSource?  (not just GridView) The code I have, OnSelectedData method, does not work and returns a zero.

2) How do I get the numbers to display differently for each page? For example, on the second page it needs to say "Showing 26 - 50 of 315"

Here's my code (C#):

```
public partial class UserControls_BloombergAllUsersControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
}
int gridViewTotalRowCount;
protected void onSelectedData(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    gridViewTotalRowCount = e.AffectedRows;
}
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int pageRowsCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;

    Total1.Text = "Showing 1 - " + pageRowsCount.ToString() + " of " + gridViewTotalRowCount.ToString();
}
private void BindGridView1()
{
    try
    {
        this.GridView1.DataBind();

        if (Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue) != null)
            GridView1.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { throw ex; }
}
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGridView1();
}
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGridView1();
}
```

}

If anyone could help that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788329/count-total-rows-of-gridview-with-pagination

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could set paging information to **Total1** text in `onSelectedData` handler as the following

```
protected void onSelectedData(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    int startRowOnPage = (GridView1.PageIndex * GridView1.PageSize) + 1;
    int lastRowOnPage = startRowOnPage + GridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
    int totalRows = e.AffectedRows;

    Total1.Text = "Showing " + startRowOnPage.ToString() +
                  " - " + lastRowOnPage + " of " + totalRows;
}
```

So you SQLDataSource should be like this sample:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     OnSelected="onSelectedData"
     ... >
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And you don't need to do anything for paging information in `GridView1_DataBound`.

I mean you could remove `OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound"` out from your GridView declaration.

**EDITED**

To set the `PageSize`, you should set a default value for it such as the following sample:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {  
        if (Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue) != null)
            GridView1.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I have set up in the code for my GridView OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" and I changed the name to "onSelectedData". It gave me an error saying it couldn't load the user control. Then when I added just the variables to OnSelectedData and the text to GridView1_DataBound like I had before, the numbers were zeros. Do I need a method in the code for the SQLDataSource? I'm not sure how to make it work.

Comment: Sorry for late, in my answer **onSelectedData** method is handler for **OnSelected** event of **SqlDataSource** control **NOT** OnDataBound event of GridView. Please see my answer again, I've edited it.

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to work! Except for one little thing, when the table first loads, lastRowOnPage shows as zero, but when I go to the other pages and go back to the first page, it shows as 10.

Comment: Did you also set default **PageSize** of GridView in aspx code? If not, I saw you have set the **PageSize** only when user change a page, then you need to set **PageSize** in page load event handler as well. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added that code but it still shows as zero. Also, it looks like the count shows for the previous DropDownList selection. For example, when I select 25 it says "1-10" and does that for the rest of the selections. The actual number of records that display are fine, but the count is off somehow.

Comment: Whenever the PageSize was changed, you have to update display text for Total1. SO try to do this everywhere after you set new value to **GridView1.PageSize**.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SqlDataSource, try this code:

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEvent Args) Handles
SqlDataSource1.Selected

  Dim cnt As Integer = e.AffectedRows

End Sub
```