# Calculate total rows in a gridview/DataSource

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have a Gridview which is filled with registered members of a pool competition. It currently has 2 pages and at the bottom I try to display this for example:  "23 out of 256 players have registered" as a label. However, in this example it only counts the 20 registered players for page 1 and then if you switch to page 2 it says "3 out of 256 players have registered". How to I alter this to count the total of registered players from all pages (Currently should be 23). Here's what I have..

```
lblPlayersCount.Text = gdvEntrants.Rows.Count.ToString & " out of " & session("maxPlayers") & " players have registered."
```

The SQL DataSource loks like this..

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSFixtures" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="
SELECT 
tblFixtures.player1, tblFixtures.resultPlayer1,
(SELECT contactname FROM tblaccounts WHERE (accountID = 
tblFixtures.player1)) AS player1_name,
tblFixtures.player2, tblFixtures.resultPlayer2,
(SELECT contactname FROM tblaccounts WHERE (accountID = tblFixtures.player2)) AS player2_name,
tblFixtures.compID, 
tblFixtures.round
FROM tblFixtures INNER JOIN tblCompetitions ON tblFixtures.compID = 
tblCompetitions.compID WHERE tblFixtures.compID = @Event_ID AND round = @Round ">


<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="compID" Name="Event_ID" />
    <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="round" Name="Round" />
</SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then the gridview starts..

```
            <asp:Gridview ID="gdvFixtures" visible="true" width="100%"  runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" DataKeyNames="compID" DataSourceID="DSFixtures" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="True">
Bla Bla Bla...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GridViewRowCollection.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrowcollection.count(v=vs.110).aspx) only counts all rows in current `GridView` page when pagination is used. To count entire rows shown by `GridView` you need to do that from data source level, i.e. `SqlDataSource`.

You can handle [`Selected`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selected(v=vs.110).aspx) event for `SqlDataSource` in code behind and use [`AffectedRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourcestatuseventargs.affectedrows(v=vs.110).aspx) integer property to show count of all output rows:

```
Protected Sub DSFixtures_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)
    lblPlayersCount.Text = e.AffectedRows & " out of " & Session("maxPlayers") & " players have registered."
End Sub
```

Similar issue:

[Count total rows of gridview with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788329/count-total-rows-of-gridview-with-pagination)